# issue with CSS tabs using checkbox hack - css only

Tags: css, radio-button

I'm trying to making my tabs work via the radiobutton hack / checkbox hack. My tabs are positioned in the bottom and when you click them the content shows up above them, however, my tabs inactive tabs disappear. Any ideas why?

Here's my demo [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sKjc4/1/)

HTML

```
    <h1> id elementum risus</h1>
<div class="tabs">

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       <div class="content">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus dapibus varius urna, ac venenatis arcu convallis consequat. In augue est, posuere auctor facilisis varius, dictum ac risus. Donec nibh justo, aliquam sed tempus quis, lobortis sed orci.
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
       <div class="content">
           Vivamus id elementum risus. In sit amet mi nulla, ac sollicitudin odio. Phasellus laoreet leo vitae velit lobortis at condimentum odio placerat. Nam sapien eros, accumsan id porttitor a, commodo ut urna. Cras dignissim metus quis enim placerat lobortis.
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           Phasellus scelerisque luctus ligula, a consequat orci posuere rutrum. Sed ipsum nisi, ullamcorper eget fermentum a, dignissim sed dolor. Mauris viverra pretium ante, eu mollis nisi volutpat quis. Nunc neque erat, pharetra in feugiat eget, faucibus id sem. 
       </div> 
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px;  
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  bottom: -10px;
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 350px;
  display: none;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
  display: block;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    bottom:-149px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason in your code you were setting the top and bottom of content to 0 which caused it to cover the other tabs. Here is a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/sKjc4/3/

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;
    /* This part sucks */
    clear: both;
    margin: 25px 0;
    min-height: 50px;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
}
.tab label {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    bottom: -10px;
}
.tab[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 350px;
    display: none;
}
[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 1;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ .content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks, however i wanted the content to go inbetween the header and the navigation! :)